# BreezeJS with json file as datasource (no server solution)

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js, breeze

I have the following scenario: I'm doing a publication lookup tool so users can find documents through a search field and filters. Right now we are working with a small budget, so all the data is stored in a json file (~60 records). If the project is successfull, we will have a server with a database and a couple of thousand records.

I want to develop all the lookup solution using breeze, so later I will don't have to make many modifications. The problem is that I can't find information about querying a json file directly (without a server).

Do you think that this is possible?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it is possible. But I can't think of a way that is as simple as setting up a simple server. That's like following off a log with Visual Studio. Maybe you're coming from a different environment? I'd like to know. Even there, it's usually pretty easy to spin something up with some kind of http API that can return JSON.

If you only have 60 records, I'm guessing this is a prototype that you're trying to stand up in a hurry. You're so much in a hurry that you don't even want to use a server ... which is kind of odd because you need something to serve the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript files, right?

You could do it with node.js / express very easily; almost as simple as setting up an express route that reads and returns the JSON file. But that still involves a server running somewhere (the client's own machine?) and you'd have to learn some elementary node.js

You can do it entirely with HTML and JS script files and no server other than the file system.

Off the top of my head, I think I'd begin by [writing a custom Breeze ajax adapter](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/customizing-ajax) that is actually a mock: no matter what you ask of it, it returns the JSON data in its entirety.

You call this once at application start to load the entities into an EntityManager cache. Then make all subsequent queries be local queries. You can set the EntityManager default query strategy to turn all queries into local queries by default.

No matter what you do, you'll have to [define metadata](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/breeze-metadata-format) to describe the entity types in your JSON data. I'm guessing you only have one type so that should be simple and quick.

You'll also have to do something to tell Breeze what kind of entity you're querying. Adding `.toType('Foo');` to the end of your queries may be sufficient. You can always delve into the [`JsonResultsAdapter`](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/web-service-data-mapping) if you need something fancier at a lower level of the stack.

None of this is hard. But none of it is Breeze 101 either. You're not following what we've thought of as a typical application development path. Maybe we're missing something. I'll be curious to see if people can relate to your situation.

Comment: It's not a prototype. Right now I have to develop two lookup solutions with small json datasources (but more are comming). For this reason I want to develop a generic lookup solution (with some kind of omnibox search and filters). If I can bind breeze to json datasources for these simple projects, then, in bigger ones, I will have to change only the breeze configuration to load json from a server, without changing anything else.